# How to get a string of row in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql

This is my Table

```
MY_TABLE

| id | first4 | last4 | reason |
--------------------------------
|  1 |   123  |  456  | Cancel |
|  2 |   123  |  789  | Correct|
```

**Problem**

> It's go into the loop and get the info but at the end it only show the last row

**example:**

```
id = 1 
first4 = 123 
last4 = 456 
reason = cancel
```

What i try to achieve is a string that render like this :

```
id = 1,2;
first4 = 123,123;
last4 = 456,789;
reason = Cancel,Correct
```

IN **C#** i use

```
try
{
    SqlDataReader render = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (render.Read())
    {
        while (render.Read())
        {
            column = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            column["id"] = string.Join(",", render["id"]);
            column["first4"] = string.Join(",", render["first4"]);
            column["last4"] = string.Join(",", render["last4"]);
            column["reason"] = string.Join(",", render["reason"]);

            rows.Add(column);
        }
        render.close();
    }
}
catch (Excecption ex)
{
    console.writeline(ex);
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```

Call the table

```
foreach (Dictionary<string, string> column in rows)
{
    interchange.DownloadBlacklist.id = column["id"] ;
    interchange.DownloadBlacklist.first4 = column["first4"];
    interchange.DownloadBlacklist.last4 = column["last4"];
    interchange.DownloadBlacklist.status =  column["status"];
}
```

What is the simplest way to achieve it? Since i manage to pull out the information but i get only the last row of the table but not how i tried to achieve it.

Comment: Can You specify what is `interchange` and it's `DownloadBlackiist`? From the example above it looks like You are just overwritting the variable located within `DownloadBlacklist`.

Comment: @Tatranskymedved its another cs file that i would to transfer the data into diffrent cs file i like.

Comment: Honestly, code specifications/information if <ID> is a string or list<string> or dicitonary<key,sting> ... this is what is missed there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might do the trick for you

```
SqlDataReader render = cmd.ExecuteReader();
List<string> IdList = new List<string>();
List<string> First4List = new List<string>();
List<string> Last4List = new List<string>();
List<string> ReasonList = new List<string>();
while (render.Read())
{
    IdList.Add(render["id"].ToString());
    First4List.Add(render["first4"].ToString());
    Last4List.Add(render["last4"].ToString());
    ReasonList.Add(render["reason"].ToString());
}
render.close();
string idstr = string.Join(",", IdList);
string first4str = string.Join(",", First4List);
string last4str = string.Join(",", Last4List);
string reasonstr = string.Join(",", ReasonList);
```

Try using `Using` for SQL Connection and Commands. That will help you getting rid of `final` block and getting your connection & command close.

**A glimpse on the code.**

Created the list of strings i.e. `List<string>` for all four columns will add all the data read from the sql.

Then reading the data normally in one loop and add all the data in the list respectively.

Once the data has been read and feeded in the list then just join them with `,` using Join.

Comment: cannot covert from 'object' to 'string'

Comment: @user3165474 then add a `.ToString()` to `render["id"]` etc.

Comment: IdList.Add(render["id"].ToString); cause cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'

Comment: `.ToString` should be `.ToString()` @user3165474.

Answer (score 2):

You can declare string variable to hold the value during looping.
Once done, during each `foreach` just take & concat the value with ',' .. after You will just append to the existing string (to avoid performance issues, use `StringBuilder`).

E.g.:

```
//omitted some code

StringBuilder ResultId = new StringBuilder();

SqlDataReader render = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (render.Read())
{
    ResultId.Append(ResultId.Length > 0 ? "," : "");
    ResultId.Append(render["id"]);
}
render.close();

ResultId.ToString(); //there is Your result

//omitted some code
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
while (render.Read())
{
    while (render.Read())
    {
        column = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        column["id"] = string.Join(",", render["id"]);
        column["first4"] = string.Join(",", render["first4"]);
        column["last4"] = string.Join(",", render["last4"]);
        column["reason"] = string.Join(",", render["reason"]);

        rows.Add(column);
    }
    render.close();
}
```

You have performed two while loops, but in the inner while you close your `SqlDataReader` named `render`.

This can throw an exception when you try to read again (in the external while) so you have as effect a loop.

Move `render.close()` at the end of the external while and consider to reduce in one loop your code

Comment: Im sorry i typo it. But there is no compile error. just i would like to know how to achieve my target

Comment: Please add a try catch and check if you go in catch branch after read render.Read() after the first render.close()

Comment: @user3165474 If there is a typo in your posted code, then please correct it. That way we don't try and "fix" thing that aren't really broken.